# How to prevent Flutter plugin from detaching from engine when a device is rotated?

Tags: java, flutter, plugins

I'm writing a screen recoding Flutter plugin. The recoding activity stops whenever the device is rotated and the plugin is detached from the engine.  How can I prevent that from happening so the recording will continue?

```
@Override
    public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
        context = binding.getApplicationContext();
        methodChannel = new MethodChannel(binding.getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL_NAME);
        methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
        methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(null);
        methodChannel = null;
        context = null;
        System.out.println("detaching engine");
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToActivity(@NonNull ActivityPluginBinding binding) {
        activity = binding.getActivity();
        binding.addActivityResultListener(this);
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
        }
    }
```